# Application closed erro

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I am getting the below error when I try to create a spinner control. Without the spinner control everything works fine.

```
11-28 11:39:42.704: W/dalvikvm(937): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.atria.requisitionform/com.atria.requisitionform.RequisitionForm}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.atria.requisitionform.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:27)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-28 11:39:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 11:39:42.805: W/ActivityManager(295):   Force finishing activity com.atria.requisitionform/.MainActivity
11-28 11:39:42.834: W/WindowManager(295): Failure taking screenshot for (266x425) to layer 21010
11-28 11:39:43.134: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
11-28 11:39:43.365: W/ActivityManager(295): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40ed0d08 u0 com.atria.requisitionform/.MainActivity}
11-28 11:39:43.755: I/ARMAssembler(36): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00008001_00000000 [113 ipp] (134 ins) at [0x428a56c0:0x428a58d8] in 8299291 ns
11-28 11:39:43.814: I/Choreographer(418): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 11:39:44.534: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

The layout for spinner control is as follows:

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/ddlMaterials"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/materials"
            android:prompt="@string/materialList"
             />
```

The code in the Requisition form activity is:

```
ddlMaterials = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ddlMaterials);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.materials, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ddlMaterials.setAdapter(adapter);
        ddlMaterials.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner());
        });
```

And the class that implements seOnItemSelected is:

```
package com.atria.requisitionform;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MaterialSpinner implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        Toast.makeText(
                parent.getContext(),
                "OnItemSelectedListener : "
                        + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Please helo ASAP as I am new to Android. In fact this is my first application.

Comment: can you share your MainActivity? There is a problem in line 27 in MainActivity.

Comment: the exception is self-explanatory, did you at least read it ? -1

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the spinner.
The problem that you are trying to call activity which the application can not recognize this activity's name is

```
RequisitionForm
```

make sure that this activity is declared correctly in your AndroidManifest.xml file